# Shadowcloak of Nocturnal for Followers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am a vampire and I have the Shadowcloak of Nocturnal that allows me to automatically turn invisible when I sneak.
Is there a way I can teach this to my followers?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/16531/?) to enhance their stealth. You can't really make your companions invisible, but what you could try is using a command in the console to spawn a Shadowcloak of Nocturnal and making them equip it. However I can't find you the specific item code.

Comment: My followers don't use torches and I have boots for them that are over 1000 sneak enchanted. I just taught it  would be more realistic for vampire to vanish while sneaking. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In the console, click the NPC to add the power to and use the command `addspell 17122` (17122 is the "spell" ID). This will add it to their spell (or power) book but it's up to the NPC's AI package to use it.